# Problem while populating orders and an array of products

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an e commerce web site using react, node and mongodb.
I created the order schema which comports the cmdRef(string), theClient(Id of the user) and an array of Products(with ProductId and qty) like the code below:

```
Orderchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    CmdRef:String,
    Client:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'},
    TotalProducts:[{ProductId:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product'},Quantity:Number}],
```

and now I'm trying to create the route to get all the Orders

```
    CommandRouter.get('/AllCommands',async(req,res)=>{
  try {
    const cmd= await  Command.find({}).populate({path: 'Client', select: 'firstName lastName'}).populate({path:'TotalProducts'})
    // 
    res.json(cmd)
} catch(error)
    { 
 
        return res.status(500).send({message : "error get orders"})

    } 
})
```

Here I found a problem while populating the products Id in the table
it populates the client Id and returns all information about the User but fail with the product table   [this is the full response using PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPfiS.png)

***Have any of you any Idea about how to populate the productId in the TotalProducts table?***

Comment: `TotalProducts` isn't the ref, `ProductId` is.

Comment: thnx @Joe, I know that the ref is the "ProductId" but it's in the array "TotalProducts " so I did'nt get how to populate an element in a table of objects

Answer (score 0):

Total products is not an `ObjectId`. You should be populating `ProductId` instead.

This should work.

```
const cmd = await Command
    .find({})
    .populate([
      {
        path: 'Client', 
        select: 'firstName lastName'
      },
      {
        path: 'TotalProducts'
        populate: 'ProductId'
      }
    ]);
```

Comment: thank you @Sachin Yadav  for your time but it still not working i still get error getting orders as you have said , I should polpulate the table of product Id but I didn't understand how

Comment: @asmasahraoui Sorry I did not see the mistake in my code before. I have now updated the answer. When it comes to nested population, you need to specify both `path` and `populate` properties. Please update me if it gets you the right results.

Comment: thank you very much,  this solve my problem